# Kerberos security mechanism inside PowerBuilder

Tags: kerberos, powerbuilder, sybase-ase15

I am trying to setup 'Single Sign On' authentication on our client-server application. 
Through using a 3rd party application we are able to authenticate user against the AD to connect active user when logging into Sybase/SAP iSQL tool.

When attempting to make same connection through PowerBuilder within the Database painter we cannot get a proper connection:

```
SQLCA.DBMS = "ADAPTIVE SERVER ENTERPRISE"
SQLCA.Database = "TEST_DB"
SQLCA.ServerName = "ASETEST"
SQLCA.LogId = "AGL027"
SQLCA.AutoCommit = False
SQLCA.DBParm = "Sec_Cred_Timeout=100,Sec_Network_Auth=1,Host='COMPUTERNAME',Sec_Mechanism='KERBEROS',Sec_Server_Principal='DBCOMPUTERNAME.DOMAIN.COMPANY.net'"
```

Does anyone know what I could be missing in the DBParm part of the connection string?  Creating an ODBC connection worked just as easy as iSQL.

Error message when trying to connect inside PowerBuilder is:
"Connection Denied. Attempt to set CS_SEC_NECHANISM connection property failed."

Answer (score 1):

Hi I removed the 'Sec_Mechanism' parameter and then was able to get my connection.  Problem solved!

```
SQLCA.DBMS = "ADAPTIVE SERVER ENTERPRISE"
SQLCA.Database = "TEST_DB"
SQLCA.ServerName = "ASETEST"
SQLCA.LogId = "AGL027"
SQLCA.AutoCommit = False
SQLCA.DBParm = "Sec_Cred_Timeout=100,Sec_Network_Auth=1,Host='COMPUTERNAME',Sec_Server_Principal='DBCOMPUTERNAME.DOMAIN.COMPANY.net'"
```